# how to use session to log out automatic from a pc when the user is logged in another pc

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session

I am using nodejs, angularjs and session to build my site, I want the user to log in just one pc at a time. That means,if the user is logged in the pc A, and then he  log in the pc B, the pc A will logged out automatic. I don't know how to do it with session. 
Thank you !

Comment: every page needs login? different apps of angualrjs under single?

Comment: I mean for each pc

Comment: having database or not? If yes, then take one field whether logged in or not. If logged in change the access token and assign to new pc, it will logged out user every time on old pc.

Comment: I have no database, but sessionStorage

Comment: without database, how you are making verification of user login password?

Comment: thanks very much ,I know how to do it, I can use sessionStorage to get all sessions, and check logged in or not. I have no database but api to check user login password

Comment: You were saying you are not having DB, now from some where you adopt API's. Hence, you are having DB. When you are having DB, then it's very easy to perform. You are wasting other people time. DOWN VOTE!

Answer (score 0):

Login should be for the whole application and not for separate pages.

Comment: for each computer